# Срабатывание всех функций в классе

Tags: javascript

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при активации определенной функции срабатывали все элементы в классе. То есть:

```
<div class="one">
  <div onclick="func_one();">Кролик_1</div>
  <div onclick="func_two();">Кролик_2</div>
</div>
```

Надо чтобы все функции в этом классе сработали. 
   Заранее благодарен!

Comment: > срабатывали все элементы в классе
> 
> все функции в этом классе сработали

Жестокий вопрос... Эй завсегдатые - экстросенсы с отпуска вернулись?

Comment: Nikita090, Вас интересует решение без `JQuery` или его можно использовать?

Comment: пошел исправлять ошибку молодости

переучиваюсь на экстрасенса и буду колотить бабло на других ресурсах, кто со мной?

Answer (score 2):

Немного говнокода - и вуаля!

```
<div class="one">
  <div onclick="alert(this.innerHTML);">Кролик_1</div>
  <div onclick="alert('2');">Кролик_2</div>
</div>
<script>
function dunno(cname, type){
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var classEls = [];
    for(var i = 0, il = all.length; i < il; ++i){
        if(all[i].className.indexOf(cname)+1){
            classEls[classEls.length] = all[i];
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0, il = classEls.length; i < il; ++i){
        all = classEls[i].getElementsByTagName('*');
        for(var j = 0, jl = all.length; j < jl; ++j){
            var todo = all[j].getAttribute('on'+type);
            if(todo){
                var f = new Function(todo);
                f.apply(all[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

dunno('one', 'click');
</script>
```

Да, на будущее: класс в javascript'е - это не то, что вы имеете в виду. Гуглите.
И понять, что значит "срабатывающие элементы" тоже может не каждый. Думайте, как объяснить профессиональными или более очевидными терминами.